# Assess sensitivity of a binary screening result across other continuous covariate(s)

Tags: epidemiology, sensitivity-specificity, diagnosis

I want to assess the sensitivity of a diagnostic screening test, which is a binary test (screen +ve and screen -ve). There is no continuous measure from this test - it is literally yes or no.

My question is, in addition to the sensitivity in the total sample, I would also like to see if there's a difference in sensitivity across other continuous clinical factors, for eg, age - Does the test perform better in younger ages as opposed to older. Similarly, there are other continuous measures I would like to compare sensitivity across (less than 10 clinical factors).

One way, which I know throws out a lof of information, is binning the continuous predictor and assessing performance in each group. But how can I make use of the continuous data to assess a non-linear relationship between sensitivity and age?

Comment: Do you know the actual condition (+ve or -ve) of the subjects so that you can determine false positives and false negatives?

Comment: Well - I'm only looking at diseased subjects and assessing the sensitivity of the screening test.

Comment: Have you considered logistic regression and odds ratios?